# Is there a way to get ls to listen for changes and update output similar to tail -f?

Tags: terminal, ls

I have a process that creates many files in a known directory, and the only way to tell how far along it is is to type `ls` manually. Is there a way to make the output of `ls` update automatically as new files are created, similar to how `tail -f` works? Because of their names, every new file appears at the end of the list, so I wouldn't have to worry about them appearing in the middle.

Comment: Is the program that creates the files something that instead could possibly be updated to output how far it has come, alternatively how far it has left to go? If not, a tool that is often used to detect file modifications/creation is `inotify`.

Comment: In this specific instance, yes. However I've bumped into this problem in cases where I could not edit the program, and because I couldn't find an answer to this problem on the internet. I figured it would be a useful trick to know, and may help someone else out if there is a solution.

Comment: Also, doing this without editing the program does not restrict you to receiving the output in the launch terminal, and can be turned on and off.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use command like:

```
watch ls
```

to loop execution of `ls` command

If the listing is too long you can add `-C` to `ls`

```
watch ls -C
```

Or you can create explicit loop with `while`

```
while [ 1 ]
 do
  clear
  ls
  sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Marked this as the answer for being the closest to my intentions, with the added benefit of allowing for the multi-column output of ls.

Comment: I turned this into a one-line terminal command to make it into an alias more easily:  `while [ 1 ]; do clear; ls; sleep 60; done`

Comment: @DavidScott, sure, that's possible, feel free to tune the code according to your environment and requirements

Comment: Since you want to watch a progress, something like `watch 'ls -ltr | tail'` may suit best. Note the quotes so that the shell does not interpret the `|`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a script like this that monitor every changes and after any change it makes a **ls** sorted by date. To be able to execute it you would need **inotify-tools** installed. The script would be the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY="your_directory_path"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${DIRECTORY}" | while read NEW
do
        ls -hltr
done
```

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't "poll" and update every X seconds. Instead, it will trigger a refresh when there is a reason to refresh. Presumably, it will react more quickly than `sleep 60` will allow.